# Including in-progress digital coursework on a resume

Tags: resume, software-industry, job-search, internship

I am currently applying to internships and I am in my sophomore year of college. I meet all job requirements for a job except for one major one which is AngularJS. I am enrolled in course for AngularJS on Udemy which I will complete by end of January. I was wondering if I should include that on resume when I apply and how I should include it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer:** Yes, you should include it on your resume.

All you need to do is to add it under your "Education" section as something like:

> *Institution Name* - Short course on AngularJS on Udemy  - Expected completion January 2016

That way they know you are doing the course and that you're (likely) finishing it soon.