# How to mention accreditation in progress on a Resume?

Tags: resume, job-search, applications

If you're currently studying for an Accredited Professional title and also actively job seeking, can/should you put on your resume Accredited Professional (In Progress), if you expect to take/pass the test in the couple of weeks but don't want to wait to send your resume out?

Comment: Closely related (perhaps duplicate) post of interest: [Including in-progress digital coursework on a resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/60125/73791)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Including in-progress digital coursework on a resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/60125/including-in-progress-digital-coursework-on-a-resume)

Answer (score 4):

As a rule of thumb you should tailor your resume for each job you are applying, in order to maximize your chances.

**If this job you are applying is related to the accreditation you are coursing, then include it**, as it will surely be beneficial (if it's not I suggest you *focus* on including/mentioning other aspects more related).

As you are currently coursing it yes you should mention that in the resume. I think that "(In progress)" is OK. An alternative I suggest is to mention the expected date of completion as well, for example:

> Accredited Professional on DevOps (expected completion: Sept. 15, 2020)

Comment: This is exactly correct

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it somewhat depends on the title and how close to finishing you are... if you are in a program that has a high likelihood of ending in Accreditation and a known accreditation date - I think you could say something like:

- Pending Accreditation XYZ - expected MM/DD/YYYY date

I'm not sure I'd do that for things that are 99% about passing a test, as credentials with tests that have a high failure rate are a lot less certain.  I've never, for example, seen folks list "Pending CISSP" - a security credential with a fairly serious fail rate.  Some folks study for a year to take it with formal bootcamps, some just give a shot based on professional experience - outcomes vary.  But since prep can average in the 6 months range, it seems a bit much to put a pending credential in that case.

But in stuff like college degrees, you often see pending graduation - as with several years of school complete, there's a pretty good likelihood that you'll make it through.

Answer (score 0):

If accreditation directly related to the jobs you are applying for, you should mention it on the resume you send out

Answer (score 0):

Wait until you finish the accreditation to list it on your resume.

However, you might want to share information about the courses you've completed towards the accreditation in the Education section of your resume.

A resume is a factual presentation of what you have accomplished. You hurt your credibility when you talk about what you might accomplish.